# PHP $_SESSION vars setting time limit?

Tags: php, session

I never unset a $_SESSION variable or destroy the session but the next day I'll come to the site and the session will be gone.

I'm doing a simple `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']` and then it forgets about the session.

Am I doing something wrong?  Do I set a time-limit for SESSION vars?

Why would it expire?

Thanks.

Comment: In many configurations, PHP periodically garbage collects old sessions.

Comment: [session_set_save_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

> but the next day I'll come to the site and the session will be gone.

**`Sessions`** are not meant to behave that way. **`Sessions`** expire as soon as you close your browser. You need **`cookies`** to achieve this.

You also need to have a look at  [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

You can do like this

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
```

Comment: What would be the easiest way to do this?  How can I safely use cookies intertwined with sessions?  I wrote my whole site using $_SESSION vars, will I need to make major changes?

Comment: It's in seconds I'm assuming?

Comment: [session.cookie_lifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) is the one you want. The default value of `0` tells it to delete the cookie when the browser is closed. Typically, you will want to set this to the same value as `session.gc_maxlifetime`.